# Reset button for specific fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a working form that generates a string, and by clicking on a button it places the string inside a text area box.

I also have a reset button that suppose to reset all fields but not the text area with the strings.

Here is some of my code.

HTML:

```html
<form>

<!--some more code and inputs-->

</tbody> </table> </p> <p> <input value="Generate URL" onclick="createURL1();" type="button">


<input name="result" size="70" class="clearit" type="text" ></input>
<input type="button" value="Add The Link" onClick="addtext();"></p>
<textarea id="t5" style="width:600px;" name="outputtext" ></textarea><br><br>


 </p>  </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>

<input  type="reset" value="Clear" id="reset" ></input>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reset').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.clearit').val("");
    });

});
```

I gave all the inputs that I want to reset a class (*clearit*) and the reset button got an ID: *reset*. The only field I didn't want to be reset got a different id.

it's supposed to work and its not.. Please Help :)

Comment: Change type on reset button from **reset** to **button**: `<input  type="reset" value="Clear" id="reset" ></input>` to `<input  type="button" value="Clear" id="reset" ></input>`. Also move `e.preventDefault();` last in the click-event.

Comment: @Mario `Also move e.preventDefault(); last in the click-event.`? If any function raise error – default event will be triggered, which is not desirable

Comment: @fantactuka Because it didn't work otherwise. You can test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/r9scW/

Comment: @Mario That's because your code is broken http://jsfiddle.net/fantactuka/vKynC/

Comment: @fantactuka Yepp, you're right, the **e** parameter was missing. I was thinking it was a strange behavior. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel or reset specific form values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716642/how-to-cancel-or-reset-specific-form-values)

Comment: Came across this from a chain of other duplicate questions.  Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34916946/4342563) for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

use this javascript function and exclude the element with id you dont want to reset and you can specify the way to reset either by left input blank or dropdown equal -1
and it works on IE and fire fox tesed

```
 function resetLabels()
    {
        //mainForm is the name of form
        var cells = document.mainForm.elements;
        for (var i= 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
             if(cells[i].name !='txtName')//for example to not reset by name 
            cells[i].value='';

   //    cells[i].className = '';
   //    cells[i].style.color = 'black';
   // or cells[i].value='-1' for drop down
   // or cells[i].name= '';  name and id to compare and exclude specific elements
   // or cells[i].id= '';    
   //and i suggest to name like txt... and ddl...to                                  
   //know the type by name and id or just check the type
   //of element by using  cells[i].type


        }


    }
```

Comment: Hi thank very much! though i am afraid here is a relay stupid question: I have tried to make it work but its not. When i change the type of the reset button to button and not reset its not reacting at all. and the script you gave me, am I suppose to specify the ID of the text area? the one i dont want to reset?

Comment: Then its not working, the reset button does not work when i change its type to button and when i leave it as reset, its just resets all the field:<input type="button" value="Clear" id="reset"  ></input>                                                        var cells = document.cwm1.elements;
        for (var i= 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
             if(cells[i].name !='outputtext')
            cells[i].value='';

Comment: if i understood the problem you want to call reset form but not on some elements if thats right imagine the code i provide working similar as reset button but you have choice to skip reseting the button to call this code should be like <button type="button" name="reset" onclick="resetLabels();"> manualReset</button>

Comment: Its working! I needed to make an OnClick=resetLabels()
 on the reset button