# Is it possible Javascript window.find() reset/restart

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement my own "Find in page" by using Javascript.

From the [window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find) API, I could not find any way to restart or reset the highlighted term back to the beginning.

Once the 'find' hit the end of a search iteration, there is no way to go back.

I know some of you might ask why to reinvent the wheel, Chrome already provide this functionality. My use case is I am trying to provide such functionality for a web widget, not a full page.

Update: this post has nothing to do with form submission. As there is no specific form element that I can set to the default value.

Comment: What do you mean reset? Why not just set `aWrapAround` to `true`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel or reset specific form values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716642/how-to-cancel-or-reset-specific-form-values)

Comment: Thanks Nick, you answer solved my part of the puzzle of "restart". Another use case of mine, imagine on the current page, open the Chrome dev tool. Try the following command: window.find('find'). After you find something, if you run command: window.find('findnotexist'), you will notice the previous highlighted 'find' will not go away/unhighlighted.

Comment: @TarangRathod, this post has nothing to do with form submission. As there is no specific form element that I can set to the default value.

Comment: glad to know you got your solution. Read all the posts and solutions properly they also have solutions for resetting form values

Answer (score 0):

As @nick-a-the-popcorn-king mentioned setting aWrapAround did the trick.

You can see an implementation in this other stack-overflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099234/5283424

Answer (score 0):

I always use this code to "re-initialize" window.find()
window.find documentation: window.find(aString, aCaseSensitive, aBackwards,...

```
while(window.find(' ',false,true)!==false){}
```