# Wrap around search with window.find() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the window.config() function to trigger search with a button. However, the wrap around boolean is set on true but doesn't actually work...

Syntax : `window.find(aString, aCaseSensitive, aBackwards, aWrapAround, aWholeWord, aSearchInFrames, aShowDialog);`

My code : `window.find(text, false, false, true, false, false, false);`

Do you have some ideas ?
Thank you :)

**EDIT** : I finally found the solution on this website : http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact your problem is that you were calling **[`.find()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)** on `container` instead of `window` element, that's why it isn't working because it's part of `window`object and is not accessible on HTML objects.

Just change your code to:

```
 if (window.find) {
  strFound = window.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound = window.find(str, 0, 1);
   while (window.find(str, 0, 1)) continue;
  }
 }
```

**Demo:**

This is a working demo along with your ***[updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OErQXv)***.

```js
$('#search-btn').on('click', () => {
  findString('lorem')
});

function findString(str) {
  let strFound;
  if (window.find) {
    strFound = window.find(str);
    if (!strFound) {
      strFound = window.find(str, 0, 1);
      while (window.find(str, 0, 1)) continue;
    }
  }
  if (!strFound) alert("String '" + str + "' not found!")
  return;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:scroll
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find -->
lorem
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="container">
  Le passage de Lorem Ipsum standard, utilisé depuis 1500 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  Section 1.10.32 du "De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" de Ciceron (45 av. J.-C.) "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto
  beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit
  amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
  commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" Traduction de H. Rackham (1914) "But I must explain to you how
  all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects,
  dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain
  of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage
  from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</div>

<button id="search-btn" type="button">Search for Lorem</button>
```

Comment: You define a container but you don't use it at all ? why ?

Comment: @BackSlashHaine I just used his code, but he edited the question and removed the codepen link, but anyway you are right, well pointed out.

Comment: i was checking this because i try to implement it but i would like to contain the `window.find` to a special div where i display PDF inside !

Comment: Ah, Okey I got it, ` window.find()` won't do that, but you can use `.innerText` and `indexOf()` over your `div`, to earch for something inside it.

Comment: it's what i was seeing while testing it's impossible to "contain" it to a div ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to call the `findString(text);` function. Call that with a `text` parameter and it will work:

```js
findString = function findText(text) {
  window.find(text, false, false, true, false, false, false);
  
  // syntax : window.find(aString, aCaseSensitive, aBackwards, aWrapAround, aWholeWord, aSearchInFrames, aShowDialog);
}

findString('minim veniam');
```

```css
#container {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:scroll
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
Le passage de Lorem Ipsum standard, utilisé depuis 1500
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
Section 1.10.32 du "De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" de Ciceron (45 av. J.-C.)

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
Traduction de H. Rackham (1914)

"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</div>

<button type="button" onClick='findString("lorem")'>Search for Lorem</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I do call the function with the onClick attribute of my button : <button type="button" onClick='findString("lorem")'>Search for Lorem</button>...

Comment: @Anatole so what is the issue then?

Comment: When the last item is found, I would like the search start again at the beginning of the text to find the first item again (kind of cycle).. you know what I mean ?

Comment: @Anatole you mean find duplicate item?

Comment: Not really, my issue is really about the wrap around option : don't stop when the last item of page is found but continue to search to find the first item then second etc...